How to get Session ID from tomcat?
i want to get Session ID from Tomcat.
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/sessions?path=/examples
output: OK - Session information for application at context path /examples Default maximum session inactive interval 30 minutes <1 minutes: 1 sessions 1 - <2 minutes: 1 sessions
